# Typescript - Inferring whether a function is curried

Tags: typescript

I have a function that converts multi-argument "vanilla" functions into curried functions.  If passed a single argument function, however, it keeps it as a vanilla function.  Typescript infers the return type of this function transforming function as the union of the vanilla function and the curried function.  That makes sense, those are the two possible outputs.

But when I then try to call a curried function returned by the transformer function, Typescript complains because it doesn't know whether the function I'm calling is the curried return or the simple return.

Here's the code that illustrates this:

```
// Types for illustration
type VanillaFunction = (foo: string) => string
type CurriedFunction = (bar: number) => VanillaFunction
type FunctionToTransform = (arg1: string, ...otherArgs: any[])=>string

const oneArgFunction = (myString: string) => myString
const twoArgFunction = (myString: string, myNum: number) => myString + myNum.toString()

const functionTransformer = (myFunction: FunctionToTransform) => {
    if(myFunction.length === 1) {
        return (arg1: string) => myFunction(arg1)
    } else {
        return (...otherArgs: any[]) => (arg1:string) => myFunction(arg1, ...otherArgs)
    }
}

const vanillaFunction = functionTransformer(oneArgFunction)
const curriedFunction = functionTransformer(twoArgFunction)

console.log(vanillaFunction("hello"))
//error here because TS doesn't know whether this is simple function or a curried function
console.log(curriedFunction(2)("hello"))
```

Now, I can fix it by explicitly telling TS the types of the returns, i.e.:

```
const vanillaFunction = functionTransformer(oneArgFunction) as VanillaFunction
const curriedFunction = functionTransformer(twoArgFunction) as CurriedFunction
```

But is there a way to make the compiler *infer* the correct type?

UPDATE:

Thinking about this a little more, it seems like type guards should help me by helping TS discriminate the inputs and outputs of the transform function.  So I tried this:

```
// Types for illustration
type VanillaFunction = (arg1: string) => string
type CurriedFunction = (arg2: any, ...otherArgs: any[]) => VanillaFunction
type FunctionToTransformSingleArg = (arg1: string)=>string
//Adding the additional non-optional argument is necessary to make FunctionToTransformSingleArg incompatabile
//otherwise the type guard won't work
type FunctionToTransformWithExtra = (arg1: string, arg2: any, ...otherArgs: any[])=>string
type FunctionToTransform = FunctionToTransformSingleArg | FunctionToTransformWithExtra

function isFunctionToTransformSingleArg(functionToTransform: FunctionToTransform): functionToTransform is FunctionToTransformSingleArg {
    return functionToTransform.length === 1
}

function isCurriedFunction(ambiguousFunction: VanillaFunction | CurriedFunction): ambiguousFunction is CurriedFunction {
    return typeof ambiguousFunction("test string") === "function"
}

const oneArgFunction:FunctionToTransform = (myString: string) => myString
const twoArgFunction:FunctionToTransform = (myString: string, myNum: number) => myString + myNum.toString()

const functionTransformer = (myFunction: FunctionToTransform) => {
    let returnFunction: VanillaFunction | CurriedFunction
    if(isFunctionToTransformSingleArg(myFunction)) {
        returnFunction = (arg1: string) => myFunction(arg1)
    } else {
        returnFunction = (arg2: any, ...otherArgs: any[]) => (arg1:string) => myFunction(arg1, arg2, ...otherArgs)
    }
    return isCurriedFunction(returnFunction) ? returnFunction : returnFunction
}

const vanillaFunction = functionTransformer(oneArgFunction)
const curriedFunction = functionTransformer(twoArgFunction) 

console.log(vanillaFunction("hello"))
console.log(curriedFunction(2)("hello"))
//              ^ -- Error here:  "Type 'string' has no call signature"
```

But as you can see, for some reason it is still not inferring the correct type for the curried function, notwithstanding the typeguard.  It seems to be inferring the return type of the CurriedFunction type rather than the full type.  Any ideas why?

Code is on [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/AQ4ejYBUE8AcCmBnYAzA9gJ2ASwDZ4CuSALpgIYk7oB2AUKMCfAsAGrk357kBihNAMZVawALzAAFOUwBzAIwAuYKUw4asgJTiAfCrLrZDUM0TAAwoUxqEAE35CRNcVJmyATMs4wANMAB0gegkABYImACCckheNDAA2gC62mJ6HFwEfALC1PSMpqwOObRQ6FAUNEgYmAC2AMqGeAhRsi7Sckr6ahqaqaqGxiAQEba2hkxhwOSjOE7keMA0tAC06HBzC26ENQg0JLgoNAiCyEgyMEzowDXkANaF2U6l5ZxVWPWNzXK4Qug1cJRyAAjfAIQbgMDBMKYADuOCQrFCiJYwFkhBktmAMNoAHJ9tjMLdwQVgEUnmUKm9agB1WYhACiAA8yOQ2m5Ov0NH43J4pnE-IF-FDwi0YnyEsk+gYNMSUWTcs9KdUai55SUKa9lQ0NE0WsAAD6kx4KjWVZW00JMlng8GoY2ieFqmiKzXvbWyXVySR2xwml5m97KJ0ugO1TTKH3FZ2mqkq+FG33q-2x92e1oAb3BjEwCBIVmckfJyeV-iaGlC4jEEnk4IAvjbGIXcgdLNYcHYndIaiC0ehiE7lOluFlE85Da2bPZ7TRw1Nuzhe-3pwcLFZJ07gJnGNnc-mmCx0Kg5z3CH2kJ2AEQkZD7TmyC8pKvAC9N2gXusN0CCWikYC0L6yAOwYxsqbQ1DAdTSrIyh3ikejgZB3RGIw36VPsJDYi0QHTiGsZgRBUEwVBfjgQActsyg0NsQLhHB1wEUhwAANT0eRNT+CQ6CIYYkiaJ+ICob+r7Okq7zhPhA4JlGuHKnRW7biATT7DmeaYDQklDpkG7jmu7ZTqOWagDgqCSI6OEgW6nwtJI4FOpo2jyQpO6qepy4SO0ChEUhdG2dOHnyHxTnALWwAIHgCKboZCkqfmG7uTysS+AEQRIpE0SJUkdH+YosG6PRnbstycjuAKKXQqKgVOfWQUxWpLa6R2fm1a5o7aAA-MAzUbsoXXTh+jDgoJ+wAG6cMOcVoDhom1OEkj-lh06VQJP77IIDX6VGLjCcWYmYJIGHoAtrXAPxwCCegTSlugsiSKNGQ8JeYQEOgD5LWdP4XQgV03WtbaNaOkjuJokgXk9eAvfZ4IQEFCkAHrAMsyzAPS1hYMA0IIMoz6wGYOJ3ji6PkIcVyCPMCxIAuNCUFYCAXkAA) as well.

Comment: The reason it was returning the return type of CurriedFunction was, actually, that it wasn't doing that -- it was returning a union of VanillaFunction and Curried function (the former of which was incompatible), and that was because the type guard was not working as I thought it was (see solution below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The problem with the type guard approach above is that I was trying to use a type guard on a function **return**.  The problem, I now realize, is that it doesn't really help the compiler.  Sure it tells the compiler how to discriminate between two types of functions that are going to be returned, but (without more information) which path was taken to get to one the to the two types of return functions isn't knowable until run time.

The key it turns out is to give the compiler some more information, effectively telling it: "you can figure out the return type of the function from the input type".  In other words, a conditional type that is based on the input type (as narrowed by a type guard on the *input* type, not the return type).

Basically you're saying to the compiler if input x to the function is type Y (as determined by a guard) then the return type will be type A, if input x is type Z (again, as determined by the guard), then the return type will be type B.

This was also complicated by the fact that one of the function signatures is compatible with the other so without some nominal typing/branding the conditional type wouldn't work.

Here's the solution (but where did my Sunday go!):

```
// These are the types we ultimately want TS to distinguish between: plain functions and curried
type VanillaFunction = (arg1: string) => string
type CurriedFunction = (arg2: any, ...otherArgs: any[]) => VanillaFunction

// This branding is needed to make the two function signatures incompatible.  Normally a function
// having fewer parameters is compatible with one more arguments, for good reason.
// See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters
type FunctionToTransform = ((arg1: string) => string) | ((arg1: string, ...otherArgs: any[])=>string)
type FunctionToTransformSingleArg = {type: "single", function: (arg1: string)=>string}
type FunctionToTransformWithExtra = {type: "multiple", function: (arg1: string, ...otherArgs: any[])=>string}
type FunctionToTransformBranded = FunctionToTransformSingleArg | FunctionToTransformWithExtra

// Type guard for the function we are passing in
function isFunctionToTransformSingleArg(functionToTransform: FunctionToTransformBranded): functionToTransform is FunctionToTransformSingleArg {
    return functionToTransform.type === "single"
}

// Creator functions to tell TS whether we are passing in a function with one argument or 
// more via type branding (see above).  Otherwise, our conditional type below wouldn't work 
// because everything would resolve to the same type-compatible signature for the multi-argument 
// function
function createOneArgFunction(fn: FunctionToTransform):FunctionToTransformSingleArg {
    return {type: "single", function:fn}
}
function createTwoArgFunction(fn: FunctionToTransform): FunctionToTransformWithExtra {
    return {type: "multiple", function: fn}
}

const oneArgFunction = createOneArgFunction((myString: string) => myString)
const twoArgFunction = createTwoArgFunction((myString: string, myNum: number) => myString + myNum.toString())

const functionTransformer = <T extends FunctionToTransformBranded>(myFunction: T) => {
    let returnFunction
    if(isFunctionToTransformSingleArg(myFunction)) {
        returnFunction = (arg1: string) => myFunction.function(arg1)
    } else {
        returnFunction = ( ...otherArgs: any[]) => (arg1:string) => myFunction.function(arg1, ...otherArgs)
    }
    // Conditional type that tells the compiler it can infer the return type on the basis of the input type, as
    // narrowed by the type guard
    return returnFunction as typeof myFunction extends FunctionToTransformSingleArg ? VanillaFunction : CurriedFunction
}

const vanillaFunction = functionTransformer(oneArgFunction)
const curriedFunction = functionTransformer(twoArgFunction) 

console.log(vanillaFunction("hello"))
console.log(curriedFunction(2)("hello"))

console.log(vanillaFunction("hello")("hello"))
//                  ^--  Properly errors because this not a curried function
//                       and will fail at runtime
```

Here's the code in [a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/PTAEBUAsFMGdtAQwE4IC41GgngBzqAO4ICuANmgJYC2ia0Z2RiAdmhAMpYD2oAJpVhUWAcxKDIoAEbQ0xaCwBcoXGUSUWoAGYkWAYyrcWsJCz6g9JZMkrQ%20AKBz5QANVaUyagGK6DlI6AAvKAAFCgiAIzKQjaiAJRBAHygMRoijngIAMJWNnY%20%20oaawWHIIgBMyqzYADSgAHSN3BjQyACCZbBVLNgA2gC6CYHJbiwe3r5F9vYgEJCC0sisAqKgCyzQdnY8oLQA1uiYcrw6hf6asJQiLHRWBBp63NS4dJRSZND1oKAActzItE8TEQ2km5xmYEgiAAbmltNBiMgVChENRZK0TAtHs9Xu8EIRKBhQEYENR-ghwiQ0WxYHUtP9QCJuNxzKhELAjPUIaAOJtlJA0GhcF0QCJCZASFJ6tjgABZSh6ZDcDlaNDAcCZDiKyi4NUEvaUYBeNoARQAxIRINgALQoaDW05%20Iywa0EjAOhGta0vJZo%20jIF3sy7XRB461obgOsHO8NQtDhxAHa1k1DelF%20jEZZwFJ0scDccBLYz0gFBUKlSLRNCxERDZKpeKgAA%205fCURS1bSdUa9WaMHanW6fUGwwbtazCBzRXzhdYsBL1A4aQ%20HREZYA3k5oMoAESXUQfHd06NKUJtqs1uKjzuiAC%20E9AU-OM6L8-%201AA6uKAKIAD2rILBJumS7tQ5BUKo0BHqCZxGMoFbtmO3ZNC0A4iF0pjDleiRjveW6PieL5zguABCRZ8NswRPkYRHFu%20S4HtAq7NgRsF5gWr4Ll%20GB-gB0yzBqzhiCg5gllgmCOkURAUqgyKwPua4aPYknnGssDUexs50QCDEiCuZQhCpNEccR77KBptFvgCZHLHYcTKEZmmce%20amsbmlkLrp%20lruu9jfN8qBoFYmiOR5771PhgRRaAe7LlB9j3tyWRshGSKOSYEZYAwZCcEQMCodJSCyS88lwhoSAwbmRDisSGxFWI1LsAy3IpggsIgvhUjkXCITwBSUjcNC0BxF8oAAPKoQS8B1NwVgWEYAhFIgOWdQw3CEEQs1kHwLAAOTsIQ-x7KA3IyHoiAkPAoDQENyDYBgcKHeQrJwNwZBDTsLQpKi6CZNa2IvFQeIpFcNxBbJYlfWBFCULaZRUgo7Dco5yknhYKXQGNGyrhphmnhZJnadQ9kE1pVmLnFzG%20f5oCBcFoDAfgu4KYex5sYoWgsPe96Oej0B0NA4CHTjJ54%20ZhGE%20T9ludOktcT%20-5LAzfn%20XTyCaIz24xdDEGs5VRQOVzCXTI8xhNdjZQaWWir8-QWNMZboshNQ2AcDeIgXmkda7K77txPYptCFgwuO2x1sY0L3Ai2xITO77Nae6IdQuz8VLKCwVIyMg3su27NagAA1D7qfUBF3B52kIRxP7AfOuwoXOQCrRlgAPOA13-gofAmKTjfUDZZh2Ikccaco4De9T-kfOwassBpKvfJQWghIIvemTplMGS7GnV8rNM07PVslOeHaXkkPsafUjkIf7NO3tdZBXZP%20%2007IwVH6EDQof2q4YdUAzewQooMcOdsCX2vm2ZCvZUK-1vv5e8NNZhZAWoSc4y0sCZHEnQLKngMqYABh4ZuhILCsDWCwLQzcvqzwwc4AIX0pDsgWNwLQ4kEAaFwCQdgW46jsgXqAWYNxrDrW2FIJgX18LCWQA4A%20b91av3BnPNG7IaHQGYRfNG0BO5mB7hLMmnlN5rgAPyuHcJ4RAVtlA5GsLYPg89EqB3YNCUxEww7BAbuvNEyAQgkmjrmf2DiLC5BsR-dxRNWghGOL4ooCQTbOjep8Mg3ARAhCcWMMxuMdwwE8NwHc1da7GHifURJyTLDWPyKLcocQQiZOyjkvJ%20SOQfCKUklJzjzGixqdk3J1SsmJNyf7WYL8hk0wAHrWmtN8AACkqfAyBGDXSEQGaQ0BzqXUOOsZoFVSl5FEiebkwyDn72WNVTw2h1A5WwcgXQVA0RAA).